# control-drag from view controller in ipad storyboard to toolbar not auto-scrolling storyboard

Tags: ipad, storyboard, drag, toolbar, viewcontroller

I just saw a video demo of control-dragging from the view controller icon for an ipad storyboard at the bottom of a view controller to the toolbar within that view controller. While the view controller icon and the toolbar are not on the screen at the same time, the dragging actually scrolls the storyboard enabling the connection between the two.

However, in my ipad storyboard I am unable to make that auto-scrolling happen and thus unable to complete the control-drag.

Is there a way to make the storyboard scrolling happen while control dragging? I thought of temporarily moving the toolbar to the bottom of the screen to make the connection and then moving it back. But the storyboard won't auto-scroll to let me do that either. I'm using a 13" macbook pro. There appears to be no zoom setting that will have both on the screen at the same time.

Alternately, can someone tell me if there is an alternate way to accomplish that? Which part of the code would I control-drag to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

according to this, one can accomplish the same by control-dragging to the icon of the corresponding element (in my case the toolbar) in "document outline pane" which sits between the project navigator and the (storyboard) canvas.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

doing so would bypass the inability to autoscroll within the storyboard.